# How to clear output buffer of Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno

I have coded arduino for DHT11 which used to print humidity in first and temperature in second line. But some times when I open SerialPort I get absurd data.[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10105666/clearing-the-terminal-screen

Comment: I am sending this data from arduino to pi serially and from pi to cloud. So some times I used to receive humidity as 6767.0 on the cloud. I am printing on console just for showing an example.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

The data you are seeing has already been sent by the previous execution of the sketch before the main MCU was reset. That data resides in a small buffer within the USB interface chip (or even within the USB CDC/ACM / USB UART driver itself, depending on your OS) to which you have no access.

You just have to ignore that data. The simplest way is to put a marker at the start of your program to indicate that whatever is receiving the data should start its receiving from this point on. Something like:

```
Serial.println();
Serial.println("START");
```

Comment: You could disable reset, by adding a capacitor between GND and RESET. Though this make uploading new code less convenient.

Comment: @Gerben It also means that you can start reading partway through a line of digits giving you similar garbage at the start of your reception. Doesn't really cure the problem. Better is to use a proper protocol rather than plain ASCII text.

Comment: Good point. Didn't think of that.

Comment: I am sending this data from arduino to pi serially and from pi to cloud. So some times I used to receive humidity as 6767.0 on cloud. I am printing on console just for showing an example. So is there no way to clean output buffer of arduino when ever it starts.?

Answer (score 0):

I've circumvented this issue by sending a byte to the Arduino whenever I'm ready to receive data using this quick-and-dirty method:

```
if(Serial.available() > 0) {  // At least one byte is available
  Serial.println(millis());
  Serial.read();  // Read the (one) character to empty the buffer
}
```